# Не работает overflow: hidden

Tags: css

Хай! не работает свойство overflow: hidden в меню примера

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnqhgu9y/

часть кода который не работает

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Что делать чтоб обрезать длинное меню снизу футера?

Answer (score 5):

Вы поставили hidden для элемента UL, который не имеет фиксированной высоты.

Если хотите обрезать до футера, то создайте основной контейнер и **overflow: hidden;** присвойте к нему. А также не забывайте использовать **position: relative** (или другие) вместе с overflow.

**Добавьте в CSS:**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Добавьте в HTML (после body):**

```
<body><div class="container">
```

**Добавьте в HTML (до /body):**

```
</div></body>
```

На вашем примере: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnqhgu9y/7/

Comment: Он не обязателен в данном примере. Можно даже заменить display-ем. А так, ваш вопрос решается добавлением контейнера, за пределы которого не должен выходить UL. Пожалуйста!

Comment: А при чём тут `position: relative;`?

Comment: **overflow** без определении позиции не всегда и не везде правильно работает.

Comment: сделал с container как вы сказали, так появилось снизу подвала пустое пространство, а до этого был код чтоб таблица была на весь экран

Comment: @Vytas ну мы решили задачу, указанную выше, а не всю верстку же делаем. Остальное вам стоит самому дописать.